# recaptchalib.php: Could not open socket

Tags: php, joomla

recaptchalib.php: Could not open socket

> define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "api-verify.recaptcha.net");

this is recapchalib.php define variable, when i ping in terminal, getting below error.

```
sh-4.1$ ping api-verify.recaptcha.net
ping: unknown host api-verify.recaptcha.net
```

please advise, how to fix this error

Comment: Did you try this- https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?id=26

Comment: i just followed there response, but no luck, they advised like changing IP and so. with this thread ref i did above PING command

Comment: Do you have a working DNS server? Are you behind an HTTP proxy?

Comment: i dont have any knowledge on these two question, can you tell me, what is these, or tell some command let i shoot.

Comment: if i change the verify server to define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "74.125.236.178"); then i am getting security code validation error. (invalid capcha entered)

Answer (score 0):

it is DNS issue. problem resolved.